# Using a variable inside of a Jquery Selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use a variable inside of a JQuery Selector in conjunction with an Id to select the proper input value since I have multiple forms. How can I use a variable and an id selector together?

My Code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id"); //this grabs the id of the form being submitted
    var name = $("id #name").val();    <-- this is the line in question
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: By using standard javascript string-concatenation, `$('#'+id+' #name').val();`

Comment: Given that `id` is supposed to be unique, you can just say `$("#name").val()`.

Comment: Why do you grab the form id? You can use the submitted form element.

Answer (score 4):

Since IDs are supposed to be unique, all you really need is `$('#name')`.

In any case, if you want to find an element inside another one and you already have a reference to that element, don't concatenate selectors (what if the element does not have an ID?). Use traversal methods instead, such as [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/). For example:

```
var value = $(this).find('input[name="name"]').val();
```

Have a look at all the traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

In case you really have to build a selector dynamically, use string concatenation, as already mentioned. A selector is nothing but a string. Example:

```
$('input[name="' + inputName + '"]')
```

Comment: +1. I was almost finished typing a comment about using `'input[name="name"]'` when you edited it in.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply concatenating a string:

```
id + ' #name'
```

which makes

```
var name = $(id + " #name").val();
```

which is odd, because `id` is probably not an element, so you'll need to add a `#`:

```
'#' + id + ' #name'
```

which is still odd, because you're using id's strangely.

Answer (score 0):

Simply build up the selector string like any other string:

```
var name = $("#" + id).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the string to create the right selector, or you can use the way:
`$('#name', this).val()`, that is the same as write `$(this).find('#name').val()`